# In Apache Beam/Dataflow multi-output DoFns, how do you assign type hints to specific tags

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, type-hinting

I have a multi-output DoFn:

```
class DoFn1:
    def process(self, row) -> Iterable[Union[Dict[str, Any], pvalue.TaggedOutput]]:
        if something:
            yield some_dict(...)
        else:
            yield pvalue.TaggedOutput("bad", ...)
```

And another DoFn that consumes its outputs

```
class DoFn2:
    def process(self, row: Dict[str, Any]) -> Iterable[...]:
        if something:
            yield some_dict(...)
        else:
            yield pvalue.TaggedOutput("bad", ...)
```

And then when I use it like this:

```
pcoll = ...
pcoll = pcoll | "dofn1" >> beam.ParDo(DoFn1()).with_outputs(
    "bad",
    main="good",
)
pcoll["good"] | "dofn2" >> beam.ParDo(DoFn2())
```

I get an error that looks like this:

```
apache_beam.typehints.decorators.TypeCheckError: Type hint violation for 'dofn2': requires Dict[str, Any] but got Union[Dict[str, Any], TaggedOutput] for row
```

How can I tell Beam type checking that the `good` tag gives `Dict[str, Any]`, and `bad` gives `TaggedOutput`? Am I forced to propagate the tagged output type hints?

Comment: Related to https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/18957 - as a compromise I usually remove the union from the process return signature and e.g.`yield t.cast(t.Any, pvalue.TaggedOutput("bad", ...))`. At least preserves type checking on the main output.

Answer (score 3):

I share with you an example of the use of `TupleTag` with `Beam`.

I compose a part of my pipeline with a `PTransform` class in the `expand` method :

```py
class TeamStatsTransform(beam.PTransform):
    def __init__(self, slogans_side_inputs: PCollection[Dict]):
        super().__init__()
        self.slogans_side_inputs = slogans_side_inputs

    def expand(self, inputs: PCollection[TeamStatsRaw]) -> \
            Tuple[PCollection[TeamStats], PCollection[Failure]]:
        outputs_map1, failures_map1 = (
                inputs | VALIDATE_FIELDS >> ParDo(TeamStatsRawFieldsValidationFn(VALIDATE_FIELDS))
                .with_outputs(FAILURES, main='outputs')
        )
```

The `DoFn` class :

```py
import logging
from typing import Dict

from apache_beam import DoFn, pvalue
from asgarde.failure import Failure

from team_league.domain.team_stats import TeamStats
from team_league.domain.team_stats_raw import TeamStatsRaw

FAILURES = 'failures'


class TeamStatsRawFieldsValidationFn(DoFn):

    def __init__(self, pipeline_step: str, *unused_args, **unused_kwargs):
        super().__init__(*unused_args, **unused_kwargs)
        self.pipeline_step = pipeline_step

    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            team_stats_raw: TeamStatsRaw = element

            yield team_stats_raw.validate_fields()
        except Exception as err:
            failure = Failure(
                pipeline_step=self.pipeline_step,
                input_element=str(element),
                exception=err
            )

            yield pvalue.TaggedOutput(FAILURES, failure)
```

- In the `DoFn` class, I can `yield` the correct result in the `try` bloc
- In the `except` I can return a `TupleTag` for failures
- In the pipeline (`PTransform`) class, I instantiate the `DoFn` class that returns 2 `PCollection` via `TupleTag` and `with_outputs` method

You can access to the project from my `Github` repository : [TupleTags Beam Native](https://github.com/tosun-si/teams-league-python-dlq-native-beam-summit).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. My question was about the type hints in DoFn.process which your example does not seem to have. How does your code know that outputs_map1 is PCollection[TeamStats] and failures_map1 is PCollection[Failure] without any type hints in the DoFn?

Comment: No need to pass type hints when we work with TupleTags

Comment: When we retrieve the result of transformations with TupleTags and side output, we have 2 PCollections. One for the first returned in the DoFn and the second for the other. The type hint is not mandatory if you use it like in my example.

Comment: If you _do_ have to use type hints (in my case - company policy and linter in merge gate), how can we add type hints to the DoFn#process but not trip up the Beam type checker? Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry but I think you are not forced to propagate the `TypeHint` in the `DoFn`, I think if you adapt your code to work without type hint , it should work. In my example I have 2 PCollection with different types : one for `TeamStats` and the other with `Failure`.

Comment: I had a similar question as the OP.  I'm trying now to see if `with_outputs` can work alongside `with_output_types`.  I think that should solve the type hinting problem, right?

Comment: I will add an answer from your topic. I think you don't need to have `with_output_types` in addtion to `with_output`.